# ASP.NET Server Controls Tag for Role Based Authorization

Tags: asp.net

I've got a web form with lots fields and buttons. These fields and buttons should be enabled and disabled based on users Role i.e. 'employee', 'team leader', 'manager' etc.

Is there a way to tag each fields such as emp for employee, tm for teamleader so that I can enable or disable them with 1 or 2 lines of code?

Otherwise I will have to write lots of if else statement for each controls.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `WebControl[]` arrays in the code-behind containing the controls visible to each role:

```
WebControl[] managerControls = { someControl, otherButton, ... };
```

Comment: Thanks SLaks, I've applied your solution however I can't see Diable property. I would like users to still see the contents in ReadOnly Mode

Comment: @flybyte: That's a property of `WebControl`.  Edited.